# intergating wordpress to a static site

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I don't know if it's possible, but is it possible to integrate wordpress to a static website? I was hoping I could put all of my content in wordpress, then a static site that's already been done could connect there and show the data. Or do I need to use PHP frameworks?

Am I getting the right idea that I need to access the database wordpress uses to gain access to my content? Or do I need to connect it to my website manually?

This is the first time I've actually tackled this, so I really have no idea, plus all the results I get from google are from templated wordpress themes.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Web Site</title>
</head>
<body>

//Some content here
// I want to show an image from wordpress here
</body>
</html>
```

I don't really want a full integration, just images and content saved in wordpress would do.

Comment: Why not full integration ? *Just images & content*. What are the other things ?

Comment: You can export posts as XML. http://en.support.wordpress.com/export/

Comment: @RoyMJ I think I must have written it wrong. I'm planning to export data from Wordpress.

Comment: @Rikesh if it's full integration what do I do? I really have no use for a lot of wordpress plugins, and I'm not planning to integrate any wordpress themes for my site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress rss feeds to get the content to your website.By using DOM you can show the data on your website.Hope this helps for you.Further if you want you can use a php framework as well.But if this is the only reason you're hoping to use a framework,according to my view that's useless.Simply you can use DOM in both core php and frameworks as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple PHP script using cURL in combination with XPath to get all the images and contents from your WordPress site to show in your static site.

Here's some relevant urls for your reference:

http://php.net/curl

[XPath Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

hope it helps.